# Find all nodes of a particular label in Scala and replace them

Tags: xml, scala

I have an XML node:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            foo
        </c>
    </b>
    <b2>
           bar
   </b2>
</a>
```

I need to recursively go through every child and find a label, say in this case `b` and replace it with another label with some other text say `<b3>baz</b3>`, so that the final result looks like:

```
<a>
    <b3>
           baz
    </b3>
    <b2>
           bar
   </b2>
</a>
```

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really any nice way to do this with the standard library, but something like the following approach will work:

```
def replaceAllBs(elem: Elem): Elem = elem.copy(
  child = elem.child.map {
    case elem: Elem if elem.label == "b" => <b3>baz</b3>
    case elem: Elem => replaceAllBs(elem)
    case other => other
  }
)
```

I.e., we descend through the tree checking whether each element is a `b`, replacing it if it is, and moving on to its children if it's not.

This is a really nice use case for [zippers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_%28data_structure%29), which are designed to make updating immutable data structures more elegant. For example, using [Anti-XML](http://anti-xml.org/zippers.html) (which is unfortunately no longer maintained), you could write the following:

```
(elem \\ "b").map(_ => <b3>baz</b3>.convert).unselect.head
```

You make a selection into the tree, make some changes, and then move back to the top with `unselect`. If you're interested in this approach, [Scales XML](https://github.com/chris-twiner/scalesXml) is actively maintained and provides another Scala XML zipper implementation (although it's syntactically a little more bulky than Anti-XML's).

Comment: @Core_Dumped: Thanks for the proposed edit—that was indeed a typo, and I've corrected it myself, since it didn't look like I was able to accept your edit after it'd been rejected by other users.

Answer (score 0):

Naive recursive implementation:

```
import scala.xml.{Elem, Node}

def replace(xml: Node)(p: Node => Boolean)(elem: Node): Node = xml match {
    case x: Node if p(x) => elem
    case Elem(prefix, label, attribs, scope, child @ _*) =>
        Elem(prefix, label, attribs, scope, child.map(replace(_)(p)(elem)): _*)
    case x: Node => x
}

val xml = <a><k/><b><c>text</c></b></a>
replace(xml)(_.label == "c")(<z>TEXT</z>)
```